# Does this t.test require a lower- or upper-tail test?

Tags: r, self-study, t-test

I'm just new in the field of t.tests so I thought I will make some excersises, but the point I can't get clear is when to use a lower or upper tail t.test. For example the following example:

> 3 people which have high blood pressure get a medicine for a period of
>   4 weeks to lower the blood pressure.

What I think when I read this is:

- $H_0$: blood pressure keeps the same
- $H_A$: blood pressure gets **LOWER**

So I would think I have t use a t.test whith lower tail(I think it's called this way), I work in R the most of the time so I would use `alt = "less"`. But according to my teacher it sould be `alt="greater",` but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you compute the paired sample difference.

before - after => greater

after - before => less